# Django Facebook Userena Integration: Active Status

Tags: django, user-profile, django-facebook

I am trying to hook up Django-Facebook to use with Userena. Userena works fine on its own, but I am having problems getting Django-facebook to work with it. Once registered with Facebook, users are not given "active" status in user permissions:

[image: Not Active Status]

Which means that they cannot edit their profiles and perform other account related actions. How do I set up Django-Facebook with Django-Userena so that once registering, Facebook registered users have the same permissions as Userena registered users? I want all users to have the same capabilities whether registered through Facebook or Userena. What's the standard way to deal with this?

Models.py:

```
class Profile(UserenaBaseProfile, FacebookProfileModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')
    website = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    my_info = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: Are you sending some verification email to user? Because users has to click on that link to verify their account and then status will be active automatically. (Just a thought)

Comment: Thanks @Aamir. I am not sure how I would do that, but would appreciate any examples.. There is nothing in the django-facebook docs that suggests I would need to do that. Any ideas are appreciated!